# Earliest Time for Shnayim Mikra

Tags: halacha, shabbat, shnayim-mikra

The [Mishna Berura](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.285.3?lang=bi&with=Mishnah%20Berurah&lang2=en) allows starting shnayim mikra for the upcoming week after davening Mincha on shabbos (285:7):

> כיון שמתחילין במנחתא דשבתא לקרות פרשת שבוע הבא נחשב שוב הקורא כקורא עם הציבור וא"כ מה שכתב המחבר מיום ראשון ואילך לאו דוקא הוא.‏

May one begin shnayim mikra for the upcoming week at the time he *could* have davened mincha or only after actually doing so?

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13174/9643

Comment: This may relate to the more general question of if a community can read the morning reading in the afternoon before mincha if they were unable to. Some (many?) hold that the full morning reading with haftara is read in the afternoon before beginning mincha. That would mean Mincha Gedola is **not** by definition when a community is up to next week's section, but rather it depends when the community actually reads it

Answer (score 2):

The source for the *Mishna Berura* is from the *Darkei Moshe* ([OC 285:1](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x1238)), who says:

> ...even from the time that they started reading the *parsha* by *Mincha* on *Shabbat*...

It seems from this that it would only be after the congregation has actually read the *parsha* by *Mincha*.

Note that the *Darkei Moshe* brings a dissenting view immediately after this, which says that one may not start at on *Shabbat*, only on Sunday, since they already read on that same day from the previous *parsha*.

Answer (score 2):

In Shmiras Shabbas K'hilchasa (chapter 42, 58) it states:

> "יכול אדם להתחיל בקריאה זו
> של שנים מקרא ואחד תרגום **מיד אחרי תפילת מנחה** בשבת *אחרי שקראו בציבור* את הפרשה הרשונה של השבוע הבא״

Now it would seem that one can only start doing Shanyim Mikra V'echad Targum after having davened mincha with a congregation, as is seen from the italicized text. However the author there comments (note 218):

> "ומסתבר דהיינו מזמן מנחה גדולה שראוי כבר לקרוא את הפרשה החדשה״

This seems to be explaining the bolded text to mean that one can start Shnayim Mikra immediately after zman mincha gedolah which is the earliest time for the congregation to daven mincha.

I asked one of my Rabanim who has been and is currently a very close talmid of Rav Avigdor Neventzal Shlit"a (who was the longest-lasting chavrusa partner of Rav Shlomo Zalman zt"l) about this quandary and he himself asked Rav Neventzal about it. Rav Neventzal answered that one does not need to actually have davened mincha(neither by himself nor b'tzibur)rather one just needs to start after zman mincha gedolah. I would venture to say that this is the seeming understanding of the author's note.

I could be mistaken about the understanding of the text in SS"K but I know that Rav Neventzal holds this way.

Answer (score 1):

Two sources suggest one can read from the time the congregation has prayed *mincha*, no matter if he has prayed with them.

The Mishna Brura ([OC 285:7](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.285.3?lang=bi&p2=Mishnah_Berurah.285.7&lang2=bi)) writes (translation from the Ohr Olam MB edition)

> Since we begin reading the next week's Torah portion (in shul) during
>   Mincha on Shabbat, a person who reads from that time is considered to
>   be reading together with the public (reading)

He doesn't note that the person himself has to be attending the reading.

Similarly, Shmirat Shabbat Khilchata (vol. 3, 42:58, p. 722) writes

> A person can begin his reading for the coming week immediately
>   following the Shabbat afternoon service, that is to say, **after the
>   congregation has begun** the reading of the ensuing week's portion.

Comment: I wonder what happens if one is in a town with multiple *batei knesset*. Can you start *shnayim mikra* after the first reading in town, or only after the first reading in your *beit haknesset* (however you want to define "your")?

Comment: Yes I thought of this as well. I remember from another context (early *kabalat Shabbat* in places where the sun sets late and the whole community welcomes Shabbat early) that it has to be your *beit knesset*, the one you are used to *daven* at (see [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/41110/11501) although I didn't re-research extensively)

Comment: So your answer is that neither of the options in the question is correct: neither from technical mincha time but from when one has prayed but from when the community prayed

Comment: @msh210 I understand it from the time one's congregation has first prayed/read the Torah, whether or not the person has prayed with them

Comment: There is a stringency and leniency here: a resident of a community with no early mincha minyan may not begin till later, and a resident of a community that starts the mincha lening before mincha gedola (as some allow) could begin then.