# When may one start Shnayim Mikra for Vezos Habracha?

Tags: hoshana-rabbah, shnayim-mikra, parashat-vezot-habracha

Generally, one may start being Maavir Sidra either on Shabbos after Mincha or on Sunday (differing opinions [see here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/98279/earliest-time-for-shnayim-mikra)).

However, I have heard that for Vesos Habracha you shouldn’t start until Hoshanna Rabba. This would leave one day. Is this true? If yes, is that an obligation or only the best way possible, but one may start during chol hamoed, i.e, today, the day before Hoshana Rabbah?

Comment: I'd be very surprised if it starts hoshana rabbah. I've always understood it was the mincha after haazinu

Comment: I had heard the same as @robev. Why should this week be any different than every other week, when you can start from Mincha on the Shabbat that we begin to read it?

Comment: Some people are careful to do the weekly readings on Friday specifically. Presumably they would read this section on Hoshana Rabba

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.669.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en Mishnah Berurah 669(4)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Mishna Berura 285:18](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.285.18?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) says that the time to start is Hoshana Rabba

> אין צריך - ר"ל שאין צריך לקרות לעצמו שמו"ת דהא כבר קרא כל התורה מדי שבת בשבתו וביום הו"ר יקרא שמו"ת פרשת וזאת הברכה ואם קרא ביום שמ"ע לא הפסיד [שע"ת]:

However The [Mishna Berura in 669:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.669.4?lang=en&with=all&lang2=en) says that one should do it on Simchas Torah night

> שמחת תורה - כתב הא"ר שבש"ת לילה ויום יש להרבות בנרות בבהכ"נ לכבוד התורה שמוציאין. כתבו הפוסקים שבליל שמחת תורה יקרא הפרשה שנים מקרא ואחד תרגום שעתה הוא זמנה:

Rav Elyashiv in his Shiurim (Brachos 8A) explains that Hoshana Rabba is preferable, but by Simchas Torah night one should really get going as time is running out. However, he adds that one may start after Parshas Hazeinu even though there is a shabbos in between with a different kriah.  ([Shevet Haleivi](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1420&st=&pgnum=68) says the same thing about Shabbos Chol Hamoed on Pesach)

As far as doing it after davening on Simchas Torah once they already lained Bereishis, The [Kaf Hachaim](https://www.sefaria.org/Kaf_HaChayim_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.285.29.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) holds it is too late, but [R' Nissim Karelitz](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=51975&st=&pgnum=124) and R' Chaim Kanievsky (Halichos Chaim page 93) say you could still do it.