When do we learn the Chok l'Yisrael for parashat Vezot Habrachah?
חוק לישראל is a weekly learning study organised according to the weekly פרשה reading. It consists of readings from the פרשה itself and from נ"ך, משנה, גמרא, זוהר, מוסר and הלכה from Sunday to Thursday. Thursday night one reads 26 פסוקים from the פרשה. On Friday one reads the whole פרשה שנים מקרא ואחד תרגום.
This works for every פרשה of the חומש, except for פרשת וזאת הברכה. This one is not read on שבת but rather on שמחת תורה only. But it does have an entry in חוק לישראל just like every other פרשה.
I know that the שמו"ת is read on הושענה רבא. But when do we learn the pieces for Sunday - Thursday night?

Closely related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/126349

@msh210 Yes and no. Shnayim Mikra is an obligation and is a separate subject (though indeed incorporated into the seder for Chok l'Yisrael).

I read the following here:

פרשת וזאת הברכה לומדים עד שבת חול המועד סוכות, ושבת בראשית לומדים החל
משבת חול סוכות ואילך.

Don't know the source for this though. Maybe just a recommended הליכה.

Isn't the whole program just a recommended הליכה? Whatever works for you is great

@DoubleAA well yes and no. This seder is put together by the Ari z"l (and extended by the Chid"a). Both great Kabbalists. The chosen sections to study and the matter how to study aren't random. It has great wisdom and significance. Hence I want to know what is intended for this final parashah.
